# How to include OpenCV source code in C++ project to make it portable?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

In my C++ project I use (3.1) OpenCV Mat for (only) storing and operating matrices (thus only the **core** module is used).

Now I would like to make the code portable: if a user (running Linux or Windows or OS X) takes my code then he can compile and run it, without installing the whole OpenCV pack.

Moreover, I would like the user to run the fastest version of the code (i.e. compiled in Release mode, Optimizations, etc...).

Could you please suggest a way to do that?

I copied the source code from modules/cores to the project directory but not sure how to proceed.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by including the static library (a `.a` file) along with your package and linking to it during compile-time. Building OpenCV with `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` as an argument to `cmake` should create the static files.

Comment: Thanks. But I want the user to create those libraries because he may run a different OS than mine. I guess I have to modify the original OpenCV CMakeLists to take into account only the core module.